# Angular 7:Type 'ElementRef' is not generic

Tags: angular7

For Details:
Angular CLI: 7.0.7
Node: 10.15.1
Angular: 5.2.9

I have already tried downgrade angular Cli version but it still not working

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Actually i am trying to use DragandDrop in my module,so simply add @angular material and @angular/cdk and run my application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please uninstall @angular/material and re install @angular/material stable to your angular cli version

Comment: Previously i have already done that too.But still error is coming.

Comment: Did u run ng-build after doing this to reflect changes?

Comment: Did u imported in import statement of your ts file